# Is it safe to use Orbot with the normal Firefox browser on Android

Tags: network, cryptography, tor, firefox

I noticed that when using Orbots "VPN Mode" that my normal Firefox browser works fine and when I visit check.torproject.org it says I'm connected even though I'm not using the Tor Browser specifically. If I install the Https everywhere and NoScript extension, are there any compromises to using Tor this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using normal browser such as Firefox for Android, while browsing, **does not provide required privacy standards**, that Orfox/Orweb provides.
To be more specific:

- Orfox adds patches at the Android Java code layer to enable proxying of all Java network HTTP communications through the local Orbot HTTP proxy.
- It also removes Android permissions for Contacts, Camera, Location, Microphone and NFC.
- Features like WebRTC and support for interaction with
  Chromecasts or Roku devices are removed, due to lack of compatibility
  with proxying communication through a TCP-based network like Tor.

> [Source: Orfox: A Tor Browser for Android - Guardian Project](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orfox/)